# find/generate npmjs integrity for bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, github, netlify, package-lock.json

im totally lost..
i run static site using github and netlify, and
i got email from github today saying:

> Known moderate severity security vulnerability detected in bootstrap
>
> > = 4.0.0, < 4.3.1 defined in package-lock.json. package-lock.json update suggested: bootstrap ~> 4.3.1.

i look into my **package-lock.json**
and found this lines

```js
"bootstrap": {
            "version": "4.2.1",
            "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.2.1.tgz",
            "integrity": "blah-blah-blah-random-char"
```

i assume i should change my bootstrap version to lastest one, but i cant find the "integrity"
i will appreciate any help or clue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `package-lock.json` is auto generated on `npm` 
so you need edit `package.json` file only
don't touch `package-lock.json` !

```html
  ...
    "dependencies": {
      "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    ...
```

and you just run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

`package-lock.json` is auto-generated file. You need to edit just `package.json` and don't touch anything in the `package-lock.json`.

**package.json**

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
...
```

...

and run `npm install`.